# How can I extract data from dat file?

Tags: fortran

I want to extract values in 1,3,5,9,11,.... lines of my .dat file using a fortran code.This is my code

```
   program one
   integer x, y, z

   open (unit=10, file='try.dat', status='old')
   open (unit=20, file='run_energy.dat', status='unknown')
   dimension time(40), energy(40)


   do y=1,13
   z=2*(y-1)
   do x=(z+1),(z+1)
   read (10,*) time(x), energy(x)
   write(20,*) time(x), energy(x)
   end do
   end do
   stop
   end
```

~
But, I don't get the values correspond to the lines I mentioned above. Can you please anyone help me.

Thank you.

Comment: Firstly please use Implicit None when you write code. Once you fix that I'll have another look - while not exactly relevant here it is a such a fundamental step to avoid shooting yourself in the foot that you really must get used to using it.

Comment: Also do some indentation. Show your input data. You probably need a dummy read to skip the even lines.

Comment: Thank you very much for answers. My data set contains two columns (time and energy) and 25 lines.                                    
    
I want to extract lines 1,3,5,7 and so on. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please follow the remarks in the comments from Ian and me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to skip line (dummy read). Something like this:

```
   x = 1 
   do i=1,13
     ! Read only if at correct line of 'try.dat'
     if (i == 2*(x-1)+1) then 
       read (10,*) time(x), energy(x)
       write(20,*) time(x), energy(x)
       ! Increment x 
       x=x+1
     else
       ! Skip line
       read (10,*)
     end if
   end do
```

Kind regards.

Comment: Why not use the modulo function?

Answer (score 0):

As already mentionned, the trick is to skip one line of the input file `try.dat` in order that only odd lines are written to the output file `run_energy.dat`.

Therefore the FORTRAN solution might also look like this, if the odd values of the input file shall be saved in the vectors `time` and `energy`:

```
program one
implicit none
integer, parameter :: siz = 40
integer   :: x, st
real      :: time(siz), energy(siz)
character :: line*256

open (unit=10, file='try.dat', status='old')
open (unit=20, file='run_energy.dat', status='unknown')

x = 1
read(10,'(A)',iostat=st) line
do while ((st == 0).and.(x < siz))
  write(*,*) 'x = ',x, ', line = ', trim(line)
  read(line,*,iostat=st) time(x), energy(x) 
  if (st == 0) write(20,*) time(x), energy(x)
  read(10,'(A)',iostat=st) line ! Skip one line
  if (st == 0) then   ! Read next relevant line
    x = x + 1
    read(10,'(A)',iostat=st) line 
  endif
end do
close(10)
close(20)
end
```

If no saving of data into these vectors is required then the solution is quite shorter:

```
program one
implicit none
integer :: st
character :: line*256

open (unit=10, file='try.dat', status='old')
open (unit=20, file='run_energy.dat', status='unknown')

read(10,'(A)',iostat=st) line
do while (st == 0)
  write(20,'(A)') trim(line)
  read(10,'(A)',iostat=st) line ! Skip one line
  if (st == 0) then   ! Read next relevant line
    read(10,'(A)',iostat=st) line 
  endif
end do
close(10)
close(20)
end
```

The trick is to use `iostat` in the `read` statement to detect end of file or improper matches of the `line` data to the vectors `time` and `energy`.

Hope it helps.